# Count NAs between first and last occured numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na, missing-data

Here is my toy dataset

```
df <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  7,   NA, 4,
  8,   2,  NA,
  NA,  NA, NA,
  NA,  4,  6)
```

I want to get a dataframe with a number of `NA`s for each variable only between the first and the last occurrence of numbers in each column and number of `NA`s between the first occurred number and last row. So, for this example, the desired solution is

```
desired_df <- tribble(~vars, ~na_count_between_1st_last_num, ~na_count_between_1st_num_last_row,
                       "x",     0,                              2,
                       "y",     1,                              1,
                       "z",     2,                              2)
```

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`na.trim` trims NAs off both ends or just the left or right end if we specify `sides="left"` or `sides="right"` so:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(na1 = sum(is.na(na.trim(value))), 
            na2 = sum(is.na(na.trim(value, "left")))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name    na1   na2
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 x         0     2
2 y         1     1
3 z         2     2
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an idea via base R,

```
f1 <- function(x) {i1 <- which(!is.na(x)); head(i1, 1):tail(i1, 1) }
f2 <- function(x) {i1 <- which(!is.na(x)); head(i1, 1):length(x) }

merge(stack(sapply(df, function(i) sum(is.na(i[f1(i)])))), 
      stack(sapply(df, function(i) sum(is.na(i[f2(i)])))), by = 'ind')

#  ind values.x values.y
#1   x        0        2
#2   y        1        1
#3   z        2        2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possibility using two functions:

```
fun1 <- function(x) { #count NA between first and last non NA
  idx1 <- cumsum(!is.na(x)) > 0 #identify leading NA
  idx2 <- rev(cumsum(!is.na(rev(x))) > 0) #identify trailing NA
  sum(is.na(x[idx1 & idx2]))
}


fun2 <- function(x) {#count NA between first non-NA and last element
  idx1 <- cumsum(!is.na(x)) > 0 #identify leading NA
  sum(is.na(x[idx1]))
}
```

Afterwards you just summarise your data.frame and reshape it:

```
df %>% summarise_all(list(m1 = ~fun1(.), m2 = ~fun2(.))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_pattern = "^(.)_(.*)$", names_to = c("vars", "a"),
               values_to = "x") %>%
  spread(a, x)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  vars     m1    m2
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 x         0     2
2 y         1     1
3 z         2     2
```

Comment: On my real data, I get the output as                                                                           
 # A tibble: 1 x 2
  vars  `<NA>`
  <chr>  <int>
1 NA         0 , not sure why. Is it because of the names_pattern = "^(.)_(.*)$"

Comment: probabily because of `names_pattern`. Best check `?pivot_longer` to see how to use `names_pattern`.  Maybe you can simply use `names_pattern = "^(.*)_(.*)$"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `data.table::nafill`:

```
library(data.table)
natrail <- colSums(is.na(as.data.table(nafill(df, "nocb"))))
nastart <- colSums(is.na(as.data.table(nafill(df, "locf"))))    
n1last <- nrow(df) - colSums(!is.na(df)) - nastart
n1num <- n1last - natrail

cbind(na_count_between_1st_last_num=n1num, na_count_between_1st_num_last_row=n1last)
```

output:

```
  na_count_between_1st_last_num na_count_between_1st_num_last_row
x                             0                                 2
y                             1                                 1
z                             2                                 2
a                             1                                 2
b                             0                                 0
d                             0                                 1
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(7,8,NA,NA), #0 2
    y=c(NA, 2, NA, 4),           #1 1
    z=c(4, NA, NA, 6),           #2 2
    a=c(1, NA, 1, NA),           #1 2
    b=c(NA, NA, 1, 1),           #0 0
    d=c(NA, 1, 1, NA))           #0 1
```